# How can I add a tab next to "Files" "Running" "Clusters" in the jupyter notebook dashboard?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I would like to add a new tab next to the existing tabs in jupyter notebook. I did a lot of research and I always come back to nbextensions. However, those extensions provide changes within a notebook. I wrote code (in PyCharm) that does some computations with given files. I want to implement the same code within the jupyter notebook environment by adding a tab to the menu (see image) and when the user clicks on the tab there will be an interface with more options and functions. Can someone help me with this?

[desired new tab location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3tEe.png)

Something like the nbgrader extension is also good. When clicking on the tab a new window appears.

[nbgrader extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cpUy.png)

[when clicking on the tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjK6i.png)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this using jquery, rather than pure javascript....

```js
define([
    'base/js/namespace',
    'jquery',
    'base/js/utils',
    './my_new_extension_code'
], function(Jupyter, $, utils, MyMainObjectList) {
    "use strict";

    var ajax = utils.ajax || $.ajax;
    // Notebook v4.3.1 enabled xsrf so use "notebooks ajax call" that includes the
    // xsrf token in the header data

    // This is the basic html framework the tab will switch to, when clicked
    // Think of it as a Template
    var myApp_html = $([
        '<div id="myApp" class="tab-pane">',
        '  <div id="myApp_toolbar" class="row list_toolbar">',
        '    <div class="col-sm-8 no-padding">',
        '      <h2 id="myApp_info" class="toolbar_info">My App Title</h2>',
        '    </div>',
        '    <div class="col-sm-4 no-padding tree-buttons">',
        '      <span id="myApp_buttons" class="pull-right toolbar_buttons">',
        '      <button id="refresh_myApp_list" title="Refresh myApp list"',
        '              class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i',
        '                         class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>',
        '      </span>',
        '    </div>',
        '  </div>',
        '  <div id="myApp_box_placeholder" class="row list_placeholder"',
        '            style="display: none;">',
        '    <div> Nothing to see here. </div>',
        '  </div>',
        '  <div id="myApp_box_error" class="row list_error" style="display: none;">',
        '    <div></div>',
        '  </div>',
        '  <div class="alert alert-danger version_error">',
        '  </div>',
        '  <div class="alert info">',
        '       Some info text, maybe.',
        '  </div>',
        '  <div id="myApp_box_loading" class="row list_loading" >',
        '    <div> Please wait, this may take several minutes... </div>',
        '    <div class="lds-dual-ring"></div>', 
        '  </div>',
        '  <div id="myApp_list" class="panel-group">',
        '  </div>',
        '</div>'
    ].join('\n'));

    // This is the method that load this extension
    // 'MyMainObjectList' will be defined in the file 'my_new_extension_code'
    // 'base_url' is whatever you need to call to get data to fill the template with
    function load() {
        var myApp_list = new MyMainObjectList(
            '#myApp_list',
            '#refresh_myApp_list',
            {
                base_url: /* whatever */,
            }
        );

        var base_url = /* whatever */;

        // If you have an external stylesheet, you need to add it to the head
        //     section of the page.
        $('head').append(
            $('<link>')
            .attr('rel', 'stylesheet')
            .attr('type', 'text/css')
            .attr('href', base_url + 'nbextensions/my_app/my_app.css')
        );

        // Add the template to the page (note, it will start hidden)
        $(".tab-content").append(myApp_html);

        // Add the tab that switches to your template.
        $("#tabs").append(
            $('<li>')
            .append(
                $('<a>')
                .attr('href', '#myApp')
                .attr('data-toggle', 'tab')
                .text('My New Tab')
                .click(function (e) {
                    window.history.pushState(null, null, '#myApp');
                    myApp_list.load_list();
                    console.log("My App Ran")
                })
            )
        );
    }

    // The return is to load this extension
    return {
        load_ipython_extension: load
    };
});
```